# Conditional Inner Join with two Functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have two functions. I need to decide whether to join with these two based on a BIT Value.

```
ON APEL.data_Period_dataination_Lookup_ID = CCEL.data_Period_dataination_Lookup_ID
INNER JOIN  markcommon.GetPredecessordatadataIds() AS PIDS
IF @Combined_Flag=1 
BEGIN
ON PIDS.data_Period_dataination_Identifier = APEL.data_Period_dataination_Identifier
AND PIDS.data_Period_Identifier = APL.data_Period_Identifier
END
```

Basically

if BIT=0 join with function 1 else join with function 2

I tried putting an IF Clause .. but it does not seem to work. What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: @DaleK then join with another function.

Comment: @DaleK I'm being advised to use an if condition and a temptable rather than joins.

Comment: By who and why? You would have to have a very complex query with a lot of rows to need that solution IMHO. One thing about SQL is you don't want to spend too much time trying to pre-empt performance issues. The built in optimiser is usually pretty good. If there is a performance issue, then you work out how to solve it.

Comment: @DaleK By my architect,one of the Data will be always null and i'm joining unnecessarily .. she says..

Comment: @DaleK sure.. thanks....

Comment: @DaleK Please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65245956/incorrect-syntax-near-nvarchar

Comment: Please cite the documentation you found for an `if` _clause_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add your static condition as part of the join condition and use a `LEFT JOIN` to ensure it works with the missing row. You can then use a `case` expression in your select to obtain the correct column e.g.

```
SELECT

    CASE WHEN F1.id IS NOT NULL THEN F1.MyColumn ELSE F2.MyColumn END

FROM ...

LEFT JOIN markcommon.Function1() AS F1
  ON @Combined_Cohort = 1
  AND {The rest of the join conditions}

LEFT JOIN markcommon.Function2() AS F2
  ON @Combined_Cohort = 0
  AND {The rest of the join conditions}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
    ON APEL.data_Period_dataination_Lookup_ID = CCEL.data_Period_dataination_Lookup_ID LEFT JOIN
    markcommon.GetPredecessordatadataIds() PIDS
    ON @Combined_Cohort = 1 AND
       PIDS.data_Period_dataination_Identifier = APEL.data_Period_dataination_Identifier AND
       PIDS.data_Period_Identifier = APL.data_Period_Identifier
. . .
WHERE @Combined_Cohort <> 1 OR PIDS.data_Period_dataination_Identifier IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LEFT JOIN` as follows:

```
APEL.data_Period_dataination_Lookup_ID = CCEL.data_Period_dataination_Lookup_ID
LEFT JOIN  markcommon.GetPredecessordatadataIds() AS PIDS
       ON (@Combined_Flag=1 AND PIDS.data_Period_dataination_Identifier = APEL.data_Period_dataination_Identifier
        AND PIDS.data_Period_Identifier = APL.data_Period_Identifier
        )
LEFT JOIN FUNCTION2() AS PIDS2
       ON (@Combined_Flag=0 AND <<join condition for function 2>>
        )
```

Answer (score -1):

Please also check:

```
SELECT
    IIF(F1.id IS NOT NULL,F1.MyColumn,F2.MyColumn)    
FROM ...

LEFT JOIN markcommon.Function1() AS F1
  ON @Combined_Cohort = 1 
  AND {The rest of the join conditions}

LEFT JOIN markcommon.Function2() AS F2
  ON @Combined_Cohort != 1 
  AND {The rest of the join conditions}
```

Comment: Please don't post unrelated links in your answer - they will be treated as spam and your answer removed. Also what does your answer add over the 3 existing answers?