# Incorrect syntax near 'NVARCHAR'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
CREATE TABLE #temptable
(
    Assessment_Component_Identifier NVARCHAR(50),
    Predecessor_Assessment_Component_Identifier NVARCHAR(50),
    Assessment_Period_Identifier NVARCHAR(50),
    [Level] TINYINT,
    Assessment_Period_dataination_Identifier NVARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO #temptable
(
    Assessment_Component_Identifier NVARCHAR(50),
    Predecessor_Assessment_Component_Identifier NVARCHAR(50),
    Assessment_Period_Identifier NVARCHAR(50),
    [Level] TINYINT,
    Assessment_Period_dataination_Identifier NVARCHAR(50)
);
```

I'm getting the following error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
> Incorrect syntax near 'NVARCHAR'

Comment: Inserting into a table doesn't take the same syntax as creating a table. It needs data in particular.

Comment: The [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) should always be your first port of call for syntax issues.

Comment: @DaleK okay.. now i need to execute two select statements based on a condition.

Comment: Thats not in this question... open a new one :)

Comment: @DaleK can you please join https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225811/discussion-with-dale

Answer (score 3):

If you want to insert into `#temp` table then you have to use only column names in the list as follows:

```
INSERT INTO #temptable
(
    Assessment_Component_Identifier,
    Predecessor_Assessment_Component_Identifier,
    Assessment_Period_Identifier,
    [Level],
    Assessment_Period_dataination_Identifier
) VALUES (.....);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #temptable
(
    S_No INT Identity(1, 1),
    Assessment_Component_Identifier NVARCHAR(50),
    Predecessor_Assessment_Component_Identifier NVARCHAR(50),
    Assessment_Period_Identifier NVARCHAR(50),
    [Level] TINYINT,
    Assessment_Period_dataination_Identifier NVARCHAR(50)
);

--it's better to use primary key or indexing if you are working on bulk data 

insert into #temptable  values('x','x','x',1,'x') 

select * from #temptable

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#temptable') IS NOT NULL

BEGIN

DROP TABLE #temptable

END
```

Comment: Its also best practice to list the columns being inserted into.

Comment: thanks for the correction @DaleK I will try to fallow